# How to display weekly report from current month in PHP/SQL and label it as "Week 1, Week 2, etc.."

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to display weekly report from current month in php/sql and label it as "Week 1, Week 2, etc..". Under Week 1 is the records of week 1 and so on...

Here's my current code that only displays the total number of record per week.

```
select count(*) as totalWeeklycomplaints
from tblcomplain group by week(dateposted);
```

[image: Sample OUTPUT]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Please see updated post above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the week, include it as a column:

```
select week(dateposted), count(*) as totalWeeklycomplaints
from tblcomplain
group by week(dateposted);
```

Because weeks repeat in years, I would suggest that you also include the year:

```
select year(dateposted), week(dateposted), count(*) as totalWeeklycomplaints
from tblcomplain
group by year(dateposted), week(dateposted);
```

Other than that, I can't quite tell what you are asking for.